# select 1st value with many rows out of 2 values based on column condition else 2nd value all rows ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

i have below oracle sql

```
select     *      from     a
where     a.description      in 
('Rebook All (1)', 'Created stock identifier') 
and     a.date     between     '03/18/2017 00:00:01' 
AND     '03/25/2017 00:00:00'
and     a.unit     =     '38240007294677'
```

Now result can have both description like below for a Unit number or can have 1 of the description ,  when it has both description for a Unit number i need to select only 'Rebook all (1)'(this description can be there many times as shows below in results)   description not 'Created stock identifier' and its related details from table a and when it has only 1 description out of these 2 then if 'Rebook All (1)' not there select 'Created stock identifier' and vice versa.
how do i select it?
Thanks in advance.

```
Date                       Description
```

3/20/2017 10:11:12.769000 AM    Created     stock     identifier

3/20/2017 10:10:47.775000 AM    Created     stock     identifier

3/20/2017 10:10:47.782000 AM    Created     stock     identifier

3/20/2017 8:14:41.696000 PM     Rebook     all     (1)

3/20/2017 8:14:41.885000 PM     Rebook     all     (1)

3/20/2017 8:13:51.622000 PM     Rebook     all     (1)

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `rank()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             rank() over (partition by unit order by description desc) as seqnum
      from a
      where a.description in  ('Rebook All (1)', 'Created stock identifier') 
            a.date >= date '2017-03-18' and
            a.date < date '2017-03-25' and
            a.unit = '38240007294677' 
    ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

Notes:
 - This uses the fact that "Rebook" comes alphabetically after "Created".  Hence the `desc` in the `order by`.
 - I prefer ANSI standard date formats.
 - Notice the change to the date logic, to eliminate the need for times on the dates.

Comment: Hi Gordon,
thanks for your quick help.
My bad in asking question actually there could be many rows with those 2 description  only like i have modified my original question for a unit number, then for that Unit number i need to select all rows with only 'Rebook all (1)' description not 'Created stock identifier' and its related details from table a and when it has only 1 description out of these 2 like, if 'Rebook All (1)' not there select 'Created stock identifier' and vice versa. how do i select it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i need all rows for that description, please help.

Comment: @Jack . . . Thank use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.